# Integrate pixijs - typescript in Ionic 2 with npm

Tags: typescript, ionic2, pixi.js

- npm install -g ionic
- ionic start pixiApp blank --v2
- cd pixiApp
- npm install
- npm install pixi.js --save **(version 4.1.0)**
- npm install --save @types/pixi.js **(I know it's def types for v3 :( )**
- I replace contents of pixiApp\node_modules\@types\pixi.js\index.d.ts by https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-typescript/blob/v4.x/pixi.js.d.ts
- In the default home.ts off app, i added this code :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600, {backgroundColor: 0x1099bb});
  }
}
```

- and finally, i launched the app with command: **ionic serve**

Results KO

[16:56:52]  rollup: Export 'autoDetectRenderer' is not defined by 'D:\labs\ionic2\pixiApp\src\pages\home\home.ts'

I tried many variants with only failures :(:(

Can you help me ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

This basically worked right from the start for me.  I did exactly as you described to set up a new, blank ionic project and install the pixi.js package and types.  I did the import the way you described as well.

Here are my source files for the "home" page:

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild("pixi")
  public pixiContainer: ElementRef;
  private pixi:PIXI.Application;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.pixi = new PIXI.Application(640,480,{backgroundColor:0x112266});
    let aspectRatio = (this.pixi.renderer.height / this.pixi.renderer.width);
    this.pixi.view.style.width = "100%";
    this.pixi.view.style.height = `${aspectRatio*100}%`;
    this.pixiContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this.pixi.view);
  }
}
```

**home.scss**

```
page-home {
    .pixiContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div #pixi class="pixiContainer">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And, it worked.  I've got a dark-blue pixijs canvas.

This is my current version info for ionic (since things change fast):

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Node : v7.10.0
    npm  : 4.2.0 
    OS   : macOS Sierra
```

Hope this helps!